# Tensorflow 2: Reload model with callback during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, model, callback

Is there a possibility to reload a Tensorflow model (only the weights) during a RedureLRonPlateau callback? I save the best model with highest validation performance with Model Checkpoint and want to reload the current best model when adjusting the LR.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.